# multiple records in one form - strong params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I want to create a several records with a single form, but I'm not sure how to make it work with strong params. I can make the strong params accept an array of hashes, but I'm not sure how to make the form post that, and I can make the form post a hash with integer keys, but I'm not sure how to make the strong params accept that.

I have a `Question` model and an `Answer` model. This is a `questionnaire` page, which shows all the `Question`s and lets the user create `Answer`s to them.

```xml
<h1>Questionnaire</h1>
<%= form_with url: questionnaire_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <% @questions.each_with_index do |question| %>
    <%= fields_for "answers[]", question do |af| %>
      <p><%= question.body %></p>
      <% question.options&.each_with_index do |option, index| %>
        <%= af.check_box :options, {multiple: true }, index, nil %>
        <%= af.label :options, option %>
        <%= af.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= form.submit "Submit Answers" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I get back params that look like this:

```rb
"answers"=>{"0"=>{"options"=>["0"]}, "1"=>{"options"=>["0", "2"]}}
```

So I tried using this:

```rb
  def answer_params
    params.require(:answers).permit(:question_id, options: [])
  end
```

But then I get an error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: :1, :2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this solution, but the workaround I've found so far is to change my `fields_for` to include a scope outside of `answers`, called `questionnaire`:

```xml
<%= fields_for "questionnaire[answers][]", question do |af| %>
```

Then change `answer_params` to this awkwardness:

```rb
  def answer_params
    params.require(:questionnaire).permit(answers: [:question_id, options: []])[:answers].values
  end
```